# Canvas radial gradient vs .png performance

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas

I'm trying to simulate brushes with the HTML `canvas` element. To get brush hardness, I'm using a radial gradient, but I'm not entirely sure whether it's faster to create a new radial gradient for every point or saving the radial gradient as an image and use `drawImage()` instead.

Current code:

```
var gradient = context.createRadialGradient(x, y, hardness * brushSize, x, y, brushSize);

gradient.addColorStop(0, color);
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)');

context.fillStyle = gradient;
context.fillRect(x - halfBrushSize, y - halfBrushSize, brushSize, brushSize);
```

`drawImage` (apart from creating the image):

```
context.drawImage(img, x, y);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gradients are expensive to generate contrary to images which are basically copies. They both need to go through transformation matrix and anti-aliasing process though, but there is no calculation involved with images besides from that.

**UPDATE** From the comments below people seem to get extremely variable test results depending on browser and hardware. The embedded test is not very accurate and was meant as a pointer, so for this reason I created a **[more accurate test here](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/g6wcj2ga/)**. Feel free to post results below in comments.
*-- update end --*

The following is not the world's most accurate test, but the difference is so large that you get a pretty good pointer in any case to which is faster:

```js
window.performance = window.performance || Date;
setTimeout(go, 250);

function go() {
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  // create radial gradient
  var gr = ctx.createRadialGradient(300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 0);
  gr.addColorStop(0, "#000");
  gr.addColorStop(1, "#f00");
  ctx.fillStyle = gr;

  // test gradient fill style
  var time1 = performance.now();
  for (var i = 1000; i--;) ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  var time2 = performance.now() - time1;

  o.innerHTML = "Gradient: " + time2.toFixed(4) + "<br>";

  // test cached gradient (canvas = image source)
  ctx = c2.getContext("2d");
  time1 = performance.now();
  for (i = 1000; i--;) ctx.drawImage(c, 0, 0);
  time2 = performance.now() - time1;

  o.innerHTML += "drawImage: " + time2.toFixed(4);
}
```

```html
<output id=o>Running... please wait</output><br>
<canvas id=c width=600 height=600></canvas><br>
<canvas id=c2 width=600 height=600></canvas>
```

Comment: I get `Gradient: 29.535 drawImage: 26906.9800`

Comment: I get gradient 1142.03ms and drawImage 9.24ms (http://i.imgur.com/PcLA9Ro.png). What is your hardware? Safari?

Comment: @somebody it would mean that on your setup drawing a single image of 600x600 would take about 26ms (almost 2 frames) which is way off normal behavior... Try to convert the canvas to an image (toDataURL and set that as source on an image element, then draw the image element instead).

Comment: IDK, I'm pretty sure it's just a bug/glitch. The runtime is faster for `drawImage`, but the time shows incorrectly.

Comment: Wow that's impressive how results do differ on different machines, running your code, I've got gradient ± 15ms and drawImage ± 10ms on my macbookpro 2011. But including the whole `createGradient`, `addColorStop` and `fillStyle` like OP does, I've got a *2 slower for gradient (still way less than your machine). But yeah, I do believe that even for solid colors, drawImage is faster than fillRect.

Comment: Even more impressive, on the same machine, but different browser (first results were from FF and new ones are from Chrome) I've got really different results, which are really suspicious : 3.9700( ! ) for gradient and 8060.5500 for drawImage. That seems really odd... http://i.stack.imgur.com/lW7KS.png

Comment: Then it must be a Chrome issue

Comment: Surprisingly variable results... I updated the answer with a link to a more accurate test.

Comment: Mine was http://i.imgur.com/V0wzRuf.png in FF (47 beta), and http://i.imgur.com/jWh3faX.png in Chrome (52 Canary). Win 8.1. Chrome sometimes kills my display driver running this test multiple times which could be due to some GPU wizardry in relation to gradients..

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to render a radial gradient, you can build the gradient on-the-fly, or use a png as you quoted, yet there's a third possibility : you can use a normalised gradient, that you build once, then use at will at any place/size by using the context transforms.

The code used to create the normalized gradient for a given hardness looks like :

```
var mySingleGradient =  ctx.createRadialGradient(0.5, 0.5, 0.5*hardness, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
mySingleGradient.addColorStop(0, color);
mySingleGradient.addColorStop(1, '#000');
```

Just like when you are using png, you'll run into the issue of caching the gradients for any base color + hardness. But you won't have any png resolution issue, and most probably the size of the gradients will be way smaller than the png's.

You use such a normalised gradient with :

```
function drawThatGradientHere(ctx, x, y, gradient, brushSize) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x,y);
    ctx.scale(brushSize,brushSize);
    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,1,1);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

I won't go into benchmarking, since there are too many chances to compare apples and oranges without knowing more about the use. Because for instance, the drawImage might very well perform very differently if you are using its scaled version. Mind also that by using an image, you might run into resolution issues (too high : perf, too low : aliasing), that you won't have if you are using a gradient. So even if the gradient was proved slower, you might prefer it because of the way it consistently looks.

A few questions :  do you change your hardness often ? do you change the brush size often ? do you change the start/end color of your gradient ?

It's only by answering those question and having a random set of rect/hardness that has the same average distribution of your real use case that you'll be able to benchmark/compare anything.

Last word : If it's becoming hard to say which solution is faster, its time to pick the solution relying on... some other *good* reason... :-)